# How do we row-reduce this with a variable???

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

im doing a determine what values of k give this matrix no sol, uniq sol and infinite sols. We have to use row operations and so i cant seem to turn this matrix into row-echelon form.. Any help would be great :)  this is what i have so far:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      k&-5&3&-8k\\
      -k&8&3k&11k\\
      -1&2&3&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

R2↔R3

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      -1&2&3&1\\
      -k&8&3k&11k\\
      k&-5&3&-8k
    \end{array}
\right] $$

R1=-R1
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&-3&-1\\
      -k&8&3k&11k\\
      k&-5&3&-8k
    \end{array}
\right] $$

R2+R3
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&-3&-1\\
      0&3&3k+3&3k\\
      k&-5&3&-8k
    \end{array}
\right] $$

R3-kR1
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&-3&-1\\
      0&3&3k+3&3k\\
      0&-5-2k&3k-3k&-9k
    \end{array}
\right] $$

And then i get stuck... dont know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a few more steps:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&-3&-1\\
      0&1&k+1&k\\
      0&-5-2k&3k-3k&-9k
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&-3&-1\\
      0&1&k+1&k\\
      0& 0 &(3k-3k)+(k+1)(5+2k)&-9k+k(5+2k)
    \end{array}
\right] $$

It has not solution when $(3k-3k)+(k+1)(5+2k)=0$ but $-9k+k(5+2k) \neq 0$.

Solve the quadratic equation 
$(3k-3k)+(k+1)(5+2k)=0$

and verify if the condition $-9k+k(5+2k) \neq 0$ hold.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a solution dependent on a variable k. Just assume k is a normal number and not 0, and continue like you used to.(by dividing the last row with -5-2k since 3k-3k=0). At the end, you will get a unit matrix and can determine when a solution exists.